# Flex does not recognize crossdomain.xml policy file

Tags: web-services, flex3, sandbox, crossdomain.xml

I'm using Flex 3 and I want to access a webservice on another server. I've imported the webservice (Data->Import) succesfully into my application, but when I'm accessing the functions in the code itself I get the following error:

*Warning: Domain ... does not specify a meta-policy. Applying default meta-policy "all".
This configuration is deprecated ...*

*Error: Request for resource at ... by requestor from ... is denied due to lack of policy file permissions*

*Security sendbox violation*

*Connection to ... halted - not permitted from ...*

I've put the "crossdomain.xml" policy file in the root directory of the server that the web service is installed on. This is the content of this file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
 <cross-domain-policy>
 <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" />
 </cross-domain-policy>
```

I've called the Security.loadPolicyFile() in my code and am still getting this error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you are not getting a 404 when requesting for the crossdomain.xml file. Just type http://servername:port/crossdomain.xml in your browser if you are getting the xml file in the browser and not a 404.